# Modify array inside of jsonb object

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I've got a table column (`columnName`) that holds an object. One of those object's properties (`objectKey`) is an array of strings. I want to prepend to that array a single value (`newValue`). I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this from the DB.

The closest I can get it do the following:

```
ARRAY['newValue'] || (columnName::jsonb->>'objectKey')
```

But that escapes all the characters in the original array and is technically making the original array an element in the a new array.

Is there a simple way to do this in the database?

A sample of my column looks like this:

```
{"objectKey":["one","two","three"],"objectKey2":["one","two","three"]}
```

After running a script I'd like it to be:

```
{"objectKey":["newValue","one","two","three"],"objectKey2":["one","two","three"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set()` to add a value to an array. The syntax is a bit clumsy though. You need to "fake" it with a non-existing index.

```
jsonb_set(the_column, '{objectKey,-9999}'::text[], '"newValue"'::jsonb, true)
```

The `9999` is simply a non-existing array index and by using a negative value, the new element is added at the beginning of the array [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.13.1.1.1)

---

Alternatively you can use `||` to concatenate two objects:

To append a value you can use the `||` operator as suggested by Abelisto:

```
jsonb_set(the_column, '{objectKey}', (the_column -> 'objectKey') || '["newValue"]')
```

To add the element at the start:

```
jsonb_set(the_column, '{objectKey}', '["newValue"]' || (the_column -> 'objectKey'))
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8297f479d11b4583e5547d3baf92a17)

Comment: Nice. I'm checking this with my select right now and it seems like it'll work. I'll mark as accepted once I finish testing and update. Thanks

Comment: BTW, about "there is not straightforward way to append or insert value"... After some short investigation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f0dee8de9ae0dc3e24a1931d152fe9b It seems that something wrong with operators priority, `||` and `->` in particular. Or I missed something...

Comment: @Abelisto: good idea. That does work indeed. I added an example.

Comment: ... and to prepend a value you should to use `'["newValue"]' || (the_column -> 'objectKey')` as shown in the dbfiddle example.

Comment: @Abelisto: true ;)